# No data populated in my Grid View using DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, dataset

I cannot see where I'm doing wrong. No data is populated into the grid view.

HERE is my aspx gridview code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="TeamMemberId" 
 Width="772px" CellPadding="4" 
ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" Height="16px" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" >

 <Columns>
 <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="TeamMemberLanId" HeaderText="LANID"  
     InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TeamMemberLanId"  />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="First Name" HeaderText="FirstName" 
                                   SortExpression="Name" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Last Name" HeaderText="LastName" 
                                   SortExpression="Name" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="IsActive" HeaderText="Status"  />
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
  <HeaderTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"      OnCheckedChanged="chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged" />
  </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"     OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" />
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>

 </Columns>

 <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
 <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" 
                       HorizontalAlign="Center" />
 <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
 </asp:GridView>
```

and here is my code behind.

```
 public void BindData()
 {


    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Mystring"].ToString());
        cmd.CommandText = "Select TeamMemberLanId, FirstName, LastName,IsActive from   dbo.LoanOwnerStamp ORDER BY 2,3";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            //Bind Empty grdview with Columns names in Header and "No Team Member   record found" message if no records are found in the database
            BindEmptyGridWithHeader(GridView1, ds);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
 }
```

Hope another pair of eyes can detect error in my gridview or code behind. BTW , da,ds, cmd, con are defined in the class.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        BindData();

    } 
  }
```

Query returns several rows,so there are no issues there.

Comment: Try casting the data source - (DataTable)ds.Tables[0]

Comment: So the query `Select TeamMemberLanId, FirstName, LastName,IsActive from   dbo.LoanOwnerStamp ORDER BY 2,3` returns rows? You have stepped through the code and verified that? You have a column named `2` and a column named `3` in your database table?

Comment: Is there a reason (other than preference) that you are binding the grid view in your code behind rather than using an `asp:sqldatasource`? [sqldatasource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz12d98w(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure how to use asp:sqldatasource so i fall back to code behind. sql do return rows and ordered by 2nd and 3rd column.

Comment: I would suggest to remove or fix `DataKeyNames="TeamMemberId"`. Your query does not have that column. It should be `DataKeyNames="TeamMemberLanId" `

Comment: I did not know you could specify numbers in the `ORDER BY` clause and it would order by column number.

Comment: Well karl , we are learning !! Thanks Afzalulh